# output contents of a foreach into a file

Tags: powershell

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://skynet 
ForEach($list in $web.Lists)
{

if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary")
{
    Write-Host $list.Fields
    if($list.Fields.ContainsField("marking") -eq $true)
    {
        Write-Host "found" $list.Title
    }
}
} | Out-File test.txt
```

What the title says really, the code above says something about a empty pipe :(, so how do I amend my code so it outputs to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write-Host prints directly to the console, so there's no input for your pipe statement.

You could output the message to the file directly with

```
Out-File -Append -InputObject "message"
```

It adds a newline as well.